# Fiddler Not capturing web.whatsapp.com

Tags: fiddler, whatsapp

I am creating a screen scrapping application which uses web whataspp. I want to know how the messages are being posted. I installed fiddler and enabled https and tweaked the certificates settings in it. I am unable to get any traffic from web.whatsapp.com, but fiddler is able to capture requests and responses of other websites(http, https). Please help.

Comment: What do u use, a HttpClient, WebRequest ?

Comment: the fiddler is not capturing requests from chrome itself.

Comment: Which Fiddler version you use? Does the app use websockets?

Comment: Fiddler 4. I am not aware whether it uses websockets